# Angular UI grid error restore state

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular UI-Grid in my page but it's not working well when I use group function.

Steps to get error: 
1) Save the initial state;
2) Group any colunm (age for example)
3) Restore state of the grid;

After the third step, are generate several errors: aggregation.col.treeAggregationFn is not a function.

If I remove the property "showColumnFooter", the grid work normally.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.saveState', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.grouping' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    saveFocus: false,
    saveScroll: true,
    showColumnFooter: true,
    saveGroupingExpandedStates: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'gender' },
      { name: 'company' }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };
  $scope.state = {};

  $scope.saveState = function() {
    $scope.state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
  };

  $scope.restoreState = function() {
    $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore( $scope, $scope.state );
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="gridSaveState" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-save-state ui-grid-selection ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-grouping class="grid"></div>
  <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="saveState()">Save</button>
  <button id="restore" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="restoreState()">Restore</button>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```